# Explicitly Adding Export to Excel option in SSRS rdl

Tags: ssrs-2012

I have created chart report in SSRS and i am using SharePoint to deploy the report. I need to add a "Export to Excel" button in RDL so that user can export the chart or data into excel.
I know that in rdl\SP we have the option, but i need to add this explicitly in the rdl.
How can this be done ?

Answer (score 0):

Add a textbox and set the action property to this:

```
=Globals!ReportServerUrl & "/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?" & Globals!ReportFolder & "/" & Globals!ReportName & "&Command=Render&rs:Format=Excel"
```

[image: action code]

Comment: Works great except I had to remove this part "&Command=Render" and add query string parameters based on report parameters..